# Adding Multiple Markers on Google Map using api v2

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have got a database with latitude and longitude values in it. I can show only one marker at a time. I would like to show multiple markers at the same time. How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Tommy. To get valid responses, you need to give us a LOT more information, and probably narrow the question to be more specific. Here's an oft referenced article on how to ask good questions: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very basic example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp"
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach',    -33.890542, 151.274856],
      ['Coogee Beach',   -33.923036, 151.259052],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
      ['Manly Beach',    -33.800128, 151.282085],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
    ];

    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map'));
    var i;

    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(-33.92, 151.25), 10);

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      map.addOverlay(
        new GMarker(new GLatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]))
      );
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Adding Multiple Markers on Google Map using api v2]